# Seedbox attached to nas, gigabit speed halved

Tags: networking, nas, esxi, rtorrent

I have gigabit internet, and I've confirmed I can saturate that successfully on my seedbox and main desktop via torrents when downloading directly to the local hard drives. I have an R710 running rutorrent in a VM that downloads torrents straight to my NAS which is on a separate box entirely. Torrents downloaded from my seedbox to my nas never go above maybe 45MB/s or so.

I think what the problem is, is that data coming down the cable into the R710, and then straight back out to the NAS, that's using the entire available bandwidth, locally, of 1 Gb.

So, is it possible to somehow get the rutorrent VM to make a direct connection to the seedbox with another cable? So that way, data coming into the seedbox on one cable, and then out to the nas on another?

The R710 is also running PFSense, though I don't have any manageable switches.

Comment: This should be possible. It is quite normal to pass though a PCI-e cards (e.g. a 1GB/10Gbit or HW RAID card) to a VM. So you could dedicate a card which only shows up in the seed VM. How though is another question. I never tried that on esxi.

Comment: I do this already with pfsense. The r710 has 4 ports. I know I can dedicate one of them to the vm, the question really becomes, how can rutorrent pass traffic that goes to the nas over the dedicated line?

Comment: Easiest would be to put the NAS and the 2nd NIC on their own subnet. *That assumes that the NAS has two or more NICs, or that you can set up an IP alias for twoIPs on its sole NIC)

Comment: I think I can. Nas doesn't currently have a second nic but but I'm getting an add-in card for it. If nas is on its own subnet, how would the seedbox connect to it?